# Two Colors NSMutableAttributeString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

Currently I am coloring the world "liked" in my UILabel.

I would like to know how to color everything else that appears in the label. Currently struggling with this capability as ranges always change.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mutableString = nil;
NSString *notificationText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ liked your Recap.", [[object objectForKey:@"from"] valueForKey:@"name"]];
mutableString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:notificationText];

NSString *pattern = @"(liked)";
NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:nil];

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,[notificationText length]);

[expression enumerateMatchesInString:notificationText options:0 range:range usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
    NSRange finalRange = [result rangeAtIndex:1];
    [mutableString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor orangeColor] range:finalRange];
    cell.notificationUser.attributedText = mutableString;
    cell.notificationUser.font = RobotoMedium(15.0f);
    cell.notificationTime.font = RobotoRegular(14.0f);
}];
```

Comment: Pass the base color as an initial attribute when you create the string. Then apply the 2nd color to just the needed part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rmaddy pointed out, you can set the color of the entire string first and then change the specific range next like this:

```
[mutableString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                      value:[NSColor blueColor]
                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [mutableString length])];

[mutableString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName 
                      value:[UIColor orangeColor] 
                      range:finalRange];
```